# There was and error running the selected coded Generator: 'Package restore Failed.no detail error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

When I try to use visual studio to create a Razor Page with Entity Framework Core (create page) it errors.

It starts of restoring packages and shows it trying to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` package, even though it's already included. Then fails [error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pznUZ.png), I've tried clearing nuget cache, uninstalling and reinstalling vs  and even tried it another computer that was using a community edition two version behind.

when I run package restore manually, it shows no errors.

I'd love for any suggestion on how I can resolve this or if there is a way to get a detailed error.

I could stub in the pages manually but I'm hoping to fix this to save me time later.

Comment: what `VS version`, and have you updated to latest?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.10.2  .NET Core 5

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1.Reinstall the required .Net core SDK and runtime.

2.Change the application framework to the new framework.

3.Update the packages you need from Nuget.